# get id/tag from dynamically generated seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

In my app the user chooses how many seekbars they need and then my code generates them (see below).

```
    // dynamically creates the view objects
    tL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    // creates all the fields
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfStockTanks; i++) {
        TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
        // creates the textView
        tV1 = new TextView(this);
        tV1.setText("      " + tankNum[i - 1] + ": ");
        tV1.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);

        // creates the seekBar
        sBGauge = new SeekBar(this);
        sBGauge.setMax(depthL - 1);
        sBGauge.setMinimumWidth(150);
        sBGauge.setId(2000 + 1);
        sBGauge.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        // shows the progress of the seekBar
        tVGauge = new TextView(this);
        tVGauge.setText("0-0.0\"");
        tVGauge.setId(3000 + i);

        // adds objects to row
        tR.addView(tV1);
        tR.addView(sBGauge);
        tR.addView(tVGauge);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tL.addView(tR, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // creates new tableRow
        TableRow tR2 = new TableRow(this);

        // add's a "+" button to tableRow
        buttonPlus = new Button (this);
        buttonPlus.setWidth(60);
        buttonPlus.setText("+");
        buttonPlus.setId(4000 + i);
        buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new MyPOnClickListener());

        // add's a "-" button to tableRow
        buttonMinus = new Button (this);
        buttonMinus.setWidth(60);
        buttonMinus.setText("-");
        buttonMinus.setId(5000 + i);
        buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(new MyMOnClickListener());

        // add TextView tVChange to show change from previous sqlite entry 
        tVChange = new TextView (this);
        tVChange.setText("Change");
        tVChange.setId(6000 + i);

        // add the TextView and the buttons to the new TableRow
        tR2.addView(buttonPlus);
        tR2.addView(buttonMinus);
        tR2.addView(tVChange);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tL.addView(tR2,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
    } // end for statement
```

my problem is when I use my onProgressChanged method:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    int seekId = sBGauge.getId();
    seekId = seekId - 2000;
    try {
        tVGauge = (TextView) findViewById(seekId + 3000);
    } // end try
    catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    try {
        //  sets the text of the textview
        tVGauge.setText(depth.get(progress));
    } // end try
    catch (Exception e) {}
    manualP = progress;
}
```

My problem is that all my seekBars only change the first progress bars textView, the buttons change the proper text view.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the same id to each seekbar

```
   sBGauge.setId(2000 + 1);
```

change 1 to **i**

```
   sBGauge.setId(2000 + i);
```

Comment: Thanks I cant believe I over looked that.  I also found one other mistake in the onProgressChanged method. I change the 1st line to 'int seekId = seekBar.getId();' I removed the 2nd line (because it's not really needed) and change the 4th line to 'tVGauge = (TextView) findViewById(seekId + 1000);' since I removed the 2nd line